# Codimension of intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

> Let $\text{codim}(E_i)=1$ for $i=1,...n$. Prove that $\text{codim}(\cap E_i) \le n$.

I was trying to prove it only with simple dimensions calculation - codim$(\cap E_i)  = \dim(E\setminus \cap E_i) = \dim(E\setminus E_1 \cap \dots \cap E_n) \le \dim(E\setminus E_1) + \dots + \dim(E\setminus E_i) = \text{codim}(E_1)+\dots + \text{codim}(E_i) =n $

But are all my equations and inequalities correct?

If not, any other ideas?

Comment: Your second inequality is equality. The first one, I believe is true, can you tell why?

Comment: @Alonso Delfin Because if I'm not mistaken $dim(U\cap V)= dim(U)+dim(V) - dim(U+V) \le dim(U) + dim(V)$?

Comment: Yeah that works. There various ways to see it but essentially, your final goal is to verify that $dim(E/(V\cap U)) \leq dim(E/V) + dim(E/U)$

Comment: @Alonso Delfin Could you share the other ways?

Comment: From the top of my mind, I guess that I’d try to shot first that $E/(U \cap V) \subset E/U \cap E/V$ and then the result will follow from the formula you gave.